# How do I solve Copy-Paste problem in my computer HDD folder on Ubuntu 20.04LTS?

Tags: 20.04, hard-drive, copy-and-paste

I have an HP laptop, with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and Windos10 installed in it(dual boot). I have a 1TB HDD. The problem is I am unable to **copy & paste** any file from one folder to another, and also if I right-click on any file in those folders, **cut, Move to and Rename** options are **disabled**. But this problem does not appear on the folder under **Home** ( i.e. Desktop, Documents, Downloads, Video, Picture), on this folder all **cut-paster & copy-paste** works fine. But problem is on the folders on HDD partition. How to solve this?
A few days ago Windows10 gets updated, is this problem arise for this update?

Comment: Could you open a terminal and type `sudo -l` then edit your question and add the last couple of lines?

Comment: @darth_epoxy Matching Defaults entries for bapi on Bapi-RPH:
    env_reset, mail_badpass,
    secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin\:/snap/bin

User bapi may run the following commands on Bapi-RPH:
    (ALL : ALL) ALL

Comment: So the HDD is not external, it is in the laptop? Can you type `lsblk` and post the result please?

Comment: Is the partition formatted as NTFS? Do you mount it using `fstab`?

Comment: @darth_epoxy sda       8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sda1    8:1    0   500M  0 part 
├─sda2    8:2    0  74.7G  0 part 
├─sda3    8:3    0  27.7G  0 part 
├─sda4    8:4    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5    8:5    0  97.7G  0 part /media/bapi/New Volume
├─sda6    8:6    0  97.7G  0 part /media/bapi/New Volume1
├─sda7    8:7    0  97.7G  0 part /media/bapi/New Volume2
├─sda8    8:8    0   7.6G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda9    8:9    0   976M  0 part /boot
├─sda10   8:10   0  38.2G  0 part /
└─sda11   8:11   0  23.3G  0 part /home


The problem is in the partition sda5

Comment: The HDD is inside the laptop, and this problem is since last 2 or 3days , before all was alright.

Comment: @BapiSaha Perhaps after the update, some Windows settings, such as fast startup, got reseted, Please try to disable fast startup following [this guide](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup) and check again if you are able to perform file actions on your partition.

Comment: @Bapi Saha Did you find the solution to this problem? Please tell me.